# Average of unlimited integers

Tags: java

My code keeps saying the average after each input. How could i change this so it only says it after all the inputs are well.... inputed.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RunGrades {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Enter number of students");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int X;
    X = input.nextInt();
    int grades[] = new int[X];

    for (int index = 0; index < grades.length; index++) {
        System.out.println("Enter student " + (index + 1) + "'s " + "grade");
        grades[index] = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("The average grade is");
        double average;
        double total = 0;
        total += grades[index];
        average = total / X;
        System.out.println(average);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to loop all the grades

```
for(int i=0;i<grades.length;i++){

total+=grades[i];

}

average=total/x;
```

your new code would be

```
      double average;
        double total = 0;
  for (int index = 0; index < grades.length; index++) {
        System.out.println("Enter student " + (index + 1) + "'s " + "grade");
        grades[index] = input.nextInt();
        total += grades[index];
    }

        System.out.println("The average grade is");
        average = total / X;
        System.out.println(average);
```

or

```
        double average;
        double total = 0;
  for (int index = 0; index < x; index++) {
        System.out.println("Enter student " + (index + 1) + "'s " + "grade");
        total += input.nextInt();
    }

        System.out.println("The average grade is");
        average = total / X;
        System.out.println(average);
```

Comment: now it says the average before each time it asks you to input the next grade.

Comment: i guess you misplaced my code snippet. just replace your total = (grades[0] + grades[1]); with this snippet.and it should work fine.

Comment: if you put it inside the loop just remove double average; , double total, and average=total/x; from the loop and put it outside the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a loop to add the total,

```
double total = 0;
for (double g : grades) {
  total += g;
}
double average = (total / grades.length);
```

Or add them on input and use one loop (and I would use `System.out.printf()`) -

```
double total = 0;
for (int index = 0; index < grades.length; index++) {
  System.out.printf("Enter student %d's grade%n", index + 1);
  grades[index] = input.nextInt();
  total += grades[index];
}
double average = (total / grades.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well ... I think you should calculate the average after the for loop.

```
double total = 0.0;
double average = 0.0;

for (int index = 0; index < grades.length; index++) {
    System.out.println("Enter student " + (index + 1) + "'s " + "grade");
    grades[index] = input.nextInt();
    total += grades[index];
}
average = total / grades.length; // Should calculate the last.

System.out.println("Average is "+average+".");
```

Hope this will help...